# How to embed a Youtube LiveStream with ChannelID and edit it with Javascript API

Tags: html, youtube-api

I'm trying to embed a youtube livestream in my website.
To be sure that it shows always the current livestream I use the channelID

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=[MY_CHANNEL_ID]"></iframe>
```

Now I need to use the Javasript API to know if the live is playing or not, so I add the "enablejsapi" parameter

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=[MY_CHANNEL_ID]?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

After I added the "enablejsapi" parameter the src link is broken and the livestream is not loaded.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `?` for add a new param in the URL:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=[MY_CHANNEL_ID]?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

You need to use `&` instead for add more parameters after using `?` character.

This is the fixed iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=[MY_CHANNEL_ID]&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```